# Particular concepts in integrated information theory

Tags: consciousness, semantics

Recently I have been reading about the Integrated Information Theory of Consciousness, and have been impressed by its intuitiveness, relative simplicity, explanatory power, and falsifiability.  All the work that I have read so far, however, has been about determining whether something is or is not conscious and to what extent, and the particular concepts that a conscious system analyses have been claimed to be the causal structures of its maximally irreducible cause-effect repertoires (MICE).

However, I am of the view that in a complete theory of consciousness, recognisable thoughts (or at least recognisable thoughts expressible through logical formalism) would be able to be translated into their physical correlates.  Has any work in IIT gone into the determination of relationships between particular kinds of thoughts and particular kinds of MICE?  For instance, have the phrases of the language of science: of propositional logic, predicate logic, set theory, and causal relations, been able to find counterparts in IIT?  Do forms like “*a* causes *b*”, or “for all *a*, *b*” have equivalent physical structures proposed for them?